# How convert dataverse table link to a local table in vba

Tags: performance, dataverse

I want convert specific tables from dataverse to local db ms access for performance, use vba (DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdConvertLinkedTableToLocal doesn't work and I select table ( DoCmd.SelectObject 'table', True)

eg

DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "Microsoft Access", dbDestino.Name, acTable, Tabla.Name, "tmp" & Tabla.Name, False

1850             DoCmd.SelectObject acTable, "tmp" & Tabla.Name, True
1860             On Error Resume Next

1870             DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdConvertLinkedTableToLocal

('DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "Microsoft Access", dbDestino.Name, acTable, Tabla.Name, "tmp" & Tabla.Name, False' create the table in first place)
Thanks